# How can I automate opening a Gradle failed test report in my web browser on demand after a build failure?

Tags: bash, macos, gradle, automation, automated-tests

I have a [Gradle](https://gradle.org) Java project with multiple modules.  When tests fail in one or more of the modules, an HTML test report is created under `${parentProject}/${childProject}/build/reports/tests/test/index.html`.  This test report is output to the Gradle command line as follows:

```
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///path/to/parent-project/child-project-1/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

When a test fails in this manner, I often like to open the HTML test report in my web browser, so I can interactively view the failures in a manner that is easier for me to see at a glance than looking at the text output of the failures.  I use the `open` command from my macOS [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) for this purpose.  Since the `open` target is a URL, it opens in my default browser, as desired.

```shell
open file:///path/to/parent-project/child-project-1/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

```
OPEN(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  OPEN(1)

NAME
     open -- open files and directories

SYNOPSIS
     open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-F] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-j] [-h] [-s sdk] [-b bundle_identifier] [-a application] file ... [--args arg1 ...]

DESCRIPTION
     The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is speci-
     fied, the default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files.

     If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
```

Currently to do this, I use my mouse to scroll up to the report line in the output, copy the report path, paste it into the terminal after typing `open` , and then hit enter.

This involves using multiple input devices (mouse, keyboard), and searching and identifying the line.  I would like to automate this (either within Gradle or within the shell) so that I can quickly open a failed test in my browser.  I don't want it to automatically happen on failed tests, since I tend to be doing things in the background when running the full project build, and I don't want web browser windows just popping up on me.

I'm not really sure how best to begin.  As far as I know, there isn't a way to get the previous process's output after the fact to scrape the failing test from (though if there is, that would be a potential avenue of attack).  I'm not sure if Gradle has a way to get the failed test report as a follow-up task, while still failing the build (if it does, I could use that task to get the failure).

I suppose I could write a standalone task which checks the project's build reports for failures and apply it to each subproject, using the presence of an XML file in `${subproject}/build/test-results/test` as an indicator that a test has failed (it looks like it's only being generated for failed tests, but I could be wrong).

So in short, is there a clean way to automatically open Gradle failed tests in my macOS web browser of choice as a simple shell script, alias, Gradle command, or the like that can be run after a test fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one instance of the `file:///.../index.html` **URL** in the contents of the entire scrolling buffer of the tab, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can do that:

```
tell application "Terminal" to ¬
    set tabHistory to ¬
        history of tab of ¬
        front window as text

set fileURL to ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "grep -o 'file:///.*\\.html' <<< " & ¬
        tabHistory's quoted form & "; exit 0"

if fileURL is not "" then ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "open " & fileURL's quoted form
```

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above acts on the selected tab of the front *window* in **Terminal**.

If there is a `file:///.../index.html` **URL** in the contents of the entire scrolling buffer it will be opened by the `open` *command*.

If there is more than one instance of the `file:///.../index.html` **URL** in the contents of the entire scrolling buffer of the tab, then make the following change in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* above to open the last instance of the `file:///.../index.html` **URL**:

**Change**:

```
set fileURL to ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "grep -o 'file:///.*\\.html' <<< " & ¬
        tabHistory's quoted form & "; exit 0"
```

**To**:

```
set fileURL to ¬
    last paragraph of ¬
    (do shell script ¬
        "grep -o 'file:///.*\\.html' <<< " & ¬
        tabHistory's quoted form & "; exit 0")
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be saved as a *shell script* with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang*, made *executable* and run from **Terminal**.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: This is the solution I've been using (with one tweak), and has been working well for my purpose.  Namely, I've been using `tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:fileURL}` to open the URL rather than `open`, since I want it in a separate window, rather than as a tab in an existing window.